# Why is setting timeZone values afftects the entire project, rather affecting the single instance.?

Tags: java, timezone

In my program,I have set the default `TimeZone` as the users `TimeZone` when the user logs in.

I was using this line to set the `TimeZone`

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(usersTimeZoneInMilliSecond)) ;
```

But i have noticed that the `TimeZone` of one person Changes to another location when another person get Logged in from another Zone.

**By this every person logged in from different part of the world will get the `timezone` of the last person logged in.**

Can anyone help me understand why this happens or how can i avoid that.

I pull out the **`getTimezoneOffset`** using javaScript and i need to use the value in all the other places in the program that follows. Its needed because i am developing a Calender like view and the application need to know the Date they see, not the UTC or the Server time.

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: @EelLee posted the code

Comment: All the relevant code, if you may. Because it looks like you are using one "global" TimeZone.

Comment: @EelLee I haven't declared the TimeZone anywhere else i just give this line of code to set the TimeZone

Comment: What kind of program are you writing? Web based? Client/Server?

Comment: @Can'tTell Web Based java application

Comment: @Dileep see the answers already posted here

Comment: @mschenk74 Yes i looked into it but none posted a solution they just posted why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code changes the **static** **default** timezone. If you want to change it for a specific user only, you need to save it in a non-static variable which is per user only.

Check the [TimeZone.setDefault](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault%28java.util.TimeZone%29) javadoc.

In order save timezone per user, it depends on what program you are running and in what environment.

If it is a web-based environment, I think storing timezone ID as a Session attribute is the best idea.

Comment: Okie it explains, but can you help me to fix this issue.. I need to have the specified timeZone for all the pages, i mean for the current user logged in.

Comment: How do you get the user's timezone? where do you need it and how you use it? Please add all relevant code for you question.

Comment: storing the offset value in session will solve, but it have a lot of overhead, i must set the TimeZone values one by one. ie For every Date variable i set. That is truly a problem in my case.

Comment: How about storing the timezone ID and get the offset for the needed timestamps only?

Comment: TimeZoneID will also get you the timeZone but setting that to each and every date that i have used is difficult, is there any other way to Set the default Date's TimeZone in just one Bean class ??

Comment: You stated that you want to save one timezone per user. Timezone ID should be the same for all dates for specific user, isn't it?

Comment: yes that would be great, per user is what i am looking for. But if that's not possible atleast get me a way to set it in a bean class.

Comment: But session is per user. So saving timezone ID on session, will save you **ONE** timezone for **one** user.

Comment: My issue is that the code that i am reworking contains more than a 100 Date variables all used at different occasions. So if i am setting the TimeZone from session i must set that to each one of them, else it will convert the time to the default timeZone right when i set it(i believe). And inorder to avoid it i must set timeZone to all this 100 date variables. You can call me lazy. :D

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm sying you should get the timezone ID (Africa/Gaborone for example). With this ID, you can get the offset for every timestamp you want, and all you need to save is this one ID per user.

Comment: @WhoAml Thanks for your continues support. I really appreciate that. I understand that i will get the timeZone ID. But i must set the timeZone to the java.util.Date and Calendar right..!! I considered that as a hideous task

Comment: OK. Now I understand what you want. I don't think you can set default timezone for session scope only, so you do have to set the timezone for each date. Proper use of OOP can make this process easier than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(usersTimeZoneInmilliSecond)) ;
It changes the timezone of your entire application which is a static reference. 
To maintain different time stamps for different users, you need to use ***Date*** object.

Comment: yes i accept but i m looking for the answer for the second part now.!!

Answer (score 1):

By calling `TimeZone.setDefault(..)` you change the default setting for timezone, so this change is not restricted to one special user, it affects all users if they ask for the default value.

Comment: Yea it explains but can you tell me a way to fix it..!!

Comment: Don't call setDefault unless you want to change the default for all users. Identify all places in your code where the timezone is relevant and then use the user specific timezone for calculations, formatting, etc.